# Auth component not responding

Tags: php, cakephp

In my case Auth component not responding properly. when i am login with wrong mail address it shows error but when i am login with right email address but wrong password it does not show error and redirect to authentic inner page.

AppController.php

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'email'
                    )
                ),
                'loginRedirect' => array(
                    'controller' => 'users',
                    'action' => 'index',
                )
            ),
    );
```

UsersController.php

```
public function login() {
        $this->layout = 'login';
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login($this->data)) {
                if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
                    $access_controll = $this->{$this->modelClass}->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('email'=>$this->request->data['User']['email'])));
                    if (!empty($access_controll)) {
                    $role_id = $access_controll['User']['role_id'];
                    if( ($role_id == 1) OR ($role_id == 2) ) {
                        return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'dashboards'));
                    } else {
                        die('You are not authenticate person.');
                        //$this->Session->setFlash(__('You are not authenticate person.'), 'message', array('class' => 'danger'), 'auth');
                    }
                } else {
                    die ('Something is wrong email id or password.');
                    //$this->Session->setFlash(__('You are not a register user still.'), 'message', array('class' => 'danger'), 'auth');
                }
                }
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('invalidLoginDetails'), 'message', array('class' => 'danger'), 'auth');
            }
        }
```

login.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User',array('novalidate'=>'true','inputDefaults' => array('div' => false))); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('email', array('type'=>'email', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Email', 'label'=>false)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('password', array('type'=>'password', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Password', 'label'=>false)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Login'), array('class'=>'btn btn-default btn-block btn-clean'));?>
```

Comment: cakephp 2.x ,  use $this->Auth->login()  , Use login() without arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes a headache but finally resolved. It was not any other thing there when i clear cookies and cache of my browser window it works properly then i make a logout function to clear cache and it works.

logout() :

```
public function logout() {
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

***But i can't understand that problem was also occurring in private window but private window not stores cookie then why this problem was occurring in private window..***

Thanks for your suggestion & support @AD7six

Answer (score 0):

### There's a bad call to AuthComponent::login

As written the [Auth::login method](http://api.cakephp.org/2.7/class-AuthComponent.html#_login) does not check the password:

> **If a $user is provided** that data will be stored as the logged in user.

I.e. irrespective of what `$this->data` is, [if it is truthy](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php#L611), this method call will always return true.

Note the difference to [the documentation example](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in):

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        // Important: Use login() without arguments! See warning below.
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
```

This is a change in behavior from 1.x (assumed you're using 2.x) where the same code *would* try to identify the user from the request data.

Comment: when    " if ($this->Auth->login()) { } ", it render to a blank page after form submission.

Comment: Probably one of your many `die` statements =). I suggest to remove them and read your application's log files.

Comment: no i've checked my code but there was not any die();

Comment: Well, this change alone is not going to be responsible for a white page - you need to debug/investigate, like by reading your application's log files.